# Run a function on Gunicorn graceful exit

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I'm running a Flask app (a RESTful API, to be more precise) via Gunicorn in Docker. The app stores its DB in memory and on request commits it to attached Redis DB.

The issue is that while running the app on Flask development server, it always runs the function to commit the DB when exitting, but not while running on Gunicorn.

How can I set Gunicorn to run the function when gracefully exitting?

Source code: https://github.com/creeper6530/restful-bbs/tree/redis 
The Flask app itself is at https://github.com/creeper6530/restful-bbs/blob/redis/flask/app.py 
The function I need to run in order to commit the DB is `save_db()`.

Comment: The relevant code has to be included in the question itself.

Comment: @KlausD. There's no relevant code, the issue is with the entire ecosystem.

I need to know how to configure Gunicorn properly.